# Click to hide a div for session

Tags: javascript, css

I am putting a little box on my page that I want to appear when someone comes, but when they click 'close', it disappears for their session.   Right now I have...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
</script>
```

Then simply close the div with...

```
onclick="setVisibility('divname', 'none');
```

But this is per page.  What can I add or change to set it so once they click close, it doesn't come back until they clear their session with the site?

Thanks

edit:  I am using php.  Thanks for the answers so far, can anyone point me in a direction to add the cookies?

Comment: This needs to be done server side.

Comment: You can't do that in just HTML, Javascript, and CSS alone.  You will need to use your server side language to either not write the div or auto hide the div if a session is set.

Comment: It could also be done with a cookie set from JS.

Comment: what is the server side technology you use? php or asp.net or what?

Comment: you can add a variable in the cookies, to store if it is was clicked or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a cookie with this function. Call it whenever the user hides the div.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Then on each page, add this :

```
function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

and check if they have div closed. These are direct excerpts. You will have to modify to fit your requirements. This is just the flow that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a session cookie in Javascript when they click on close, and always check against the cookie existence (or value).

(There's no need  for server side in this case)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you point me in the direction how to set the session cookie?